# Not able to connect to local MySql database "only" when connected to VPN on VM

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench, connections

Setup:
MySql installed on my Mac using Xammp
VM installed using VMware Fusion running win XP.

I am able to connect to the mysql database through my VM normally.

As soon as I connect to a VPN it stops connecting to the Mysql.

Please let me know how can I make it work so that it connects to Mysql no matter if VPN is ON or OFF.

Comment: Some VPN software changes routine rules and sends all traffic through the VPN. See if there is a setting that says something like "allow local LAN access".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better asked on [su]

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the MySQL not only has users listed by name and password, but also by "where they are coming from".  You may want to check and make sure the user is listed as being allowed to connect from "localhost".